# Relative path for image tag not working

Tags: html, css, image

My Relative Path to locate the image

```
<img src="D:\Projects\Food_Blog\Food_Blog\images\facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook-icon" />
```

My Folder Structure:

[image]

I am surely this is my correct path to where my facebook-logo.png is located at. I have no clue why it is not displaying in my web.

Comment: you are doing absolute path which is sometime did't work.
can you tell me where your source file is or html file is?

Comment: i don't understand why some people just need to flag down my post. Please show some respect towards people man.

Comment: Isn't my post very detail and easy to understand? Seriously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you not to use a full relative path, **might be that tomorrow someone will change the directory's location and then nothing will work**.

Do this:

```
<img src="../Food_Blog/images/facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook-icon" />
```

This will take you to the correct place, as it will go 2 levels up the hierarchy:

```
-Food_Blog
 -Food_Blog
  -images
    -logo.png
```

Better is you use a class for this:

```
.imgLogo {
   content:url("../Food_Blog/images/facebook-logo.png");
}
```

The CSS will complete your correct relevant path and use it like this:

```
<img class="imgLogo" alt="facebook-icon" />
```

This will provide maximum flexibility for your images and it's easier to maintain.

Comment: The syntax is giving me an error like File '..\images\facebook-logo.png" was not found.

Comment: move it to the css file or style section and check the path, it will autocomplete to your corrcet path

Comment: It still does not display.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the full path . Give like this

```
<img src="..\images\facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also provide your path like this

```
<img src="images\facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook-icon" />
```

Only if the "images Folder" exists in root of your Project.

Comment: It's always highlighting in green saying File 'images\facebook-logo.png" was not found. Even though the folder images exists and the facebook-log.png exists.

Comment: other images are appearing which are twitter & humberger?

Comment: Not appearing either

Comment: just inspect and copy img path which are coming in your code. and paste it to url. check what are you missing in path. or simply you can right click on image path and open in new window.

Answer (score 0):

with /images/ you can get directly to root directory Acccess

with ../ you can go 1 step back from your html file so with this if your html file is on root so you can use it like this ../images/IMAGENAME.jpeg